# time.Parse with custom layout

Tags: parsing, time, go

I'm trying to parse this string pattern `"4-JAN-12 9:30:14"` into a `time.Time`.

Tried `time.Parse("2-JAN-06 15:04:05", inputString)` and many others but cannot get it working.

I've read http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse and https://gobyexample.com/time-formatting-parsing but it seems there aren't any examples like this.

Thanks!

Edit:
full code:

```
type CustomTime time.Time

func (t *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    auxTime, err := time.Parse("2-JAN-06 15:04:05", string(b))
    *t = CustomTime(auxTime)
    return err
}
```

> parsing time ""10-JAN-12 11:20:41"" as "2-JAN-06 15:04:05": cannot
>   parse ""24-JAN-15 10:27:44"" as "2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what you did wrong (should post your code), but it is really just a simple function call:

```
s := "4-JAN-12 9:30:14"
t, err := time.Parse("2-JAN-06 15:04:05", s)
fmt.Println(t, err)
```

Outputs:

```
2012-01-04 09:30:14 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/XW-TifrHbH).

Note that [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) returns 2 values: the parsed `time.Time` value (if parsing succeeds) and an optional [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) value (if parsing fails).

See the following example where I intentionally specify a wrong input string:

```
s := "34-JAN-12 9:30:14"

if t, err := time.Parse("2-JAN-06 15:04:05", s); err == nil {
    fmt.Println("Success:", t)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Failure:", err)
}
```

Output:

```
Failure: parsing time "34-JAN-12 9:30:14": day out of range
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1TQ7psUB--).

**EDIT:**

Now that you posted code and error message, your problem is that your input string contains a leading and trailing quotation mark!

Remove the leading and trailing quotation mark and it will work. This is your case:

```
s := `"4-JAN-12 9:30:14"`

s = s[1 : len(s)-1]
if t, err := time.Parse("2-JAN-06 15:04:05", s); err == nil {
    fmt.Println("Success:", t)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Failure:", err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/84BB9cxFjx)):

```
Success: 2012-01-04 09:30:14 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: Your code seems to be equals to mine, and working. How strange... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @EzequielMoreno The problem in your case is that your input string contains a leading and trailing quotation mark as part of the string. Remove those and it will work. See the edited answer.

Comment: If the input string is like below: 2018-05-24 16:19:15 , the above solution does not work. Any idea how it can be solved?